# Proof of excission Axiom for singular Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Im working through the proof of the excission Axiom for singular Homology in the Bredon Homology book. I have two questions regarding this.
Bredon first defines the chain map $\gamma$ and the Chain Homotopy $T$ between $\gamma$ and the identity on the subcomplex of affine simplicies. then right after Lemma 17.1 on page 225 he extends this definitions of $T:\Delta_p(X) \to \Delta_{p+1}(X),\gamma:\Delta_p(X) \to \Delta_p(X)$ on the hole $\Delta(X)$. He writes down four conditions he want to have on this extensions. I don't understand the fours condition. It says that $\gamma(\sigma)$ and $T(\sigma)$ should be chains in $im(\sigma)$.
What does this mean? $\gamma(\sigma)$ is a map $\Delta_p \to X$ how can a map lie in the image of another map? How is this meant. Then he says after it that the (4) condition just follows by naturality why is this the case?

The other thing I wanted to ask is probably related. Let $U$ be an open cover of $X$. In The proof of 17.7 Bredon claims that $T_k(c)$ is $U$-small i.e the image of it lies in one element of the open cover. He just writes that this is by naturality. I abosulutly dont see why this is true. Is this related to the (4) point or why is this true?

Answer (score 4):

In general, to say a chain $c\in\Delta_p(X)$ lies in a subspace $A\subseteq X$ just means it is contained in the subcomplex $\Delta_p(A)\subseteq\Delta_p(X)$, equivalently its support (the union of the images of its simplices) is contained in $A$. In this specific case, this follows by applying naturality to the map $\sigma\colon\Delta^p\rightarrow X$, which implies that $\gamma(\sigma)=\gamma\sigma_{\ast}(\iota_p)=\sigma_{\ast}(\gamma\iota_p)$. An analogous argument holds for $T$.

For your second question, the point you've omitted is that $c$ was a $U$-small chain to begin with. That is, $c$ is a linear combination of singular simplices each lying in some element of $U$ (they don't all need to lie in the same element, to be clear), but $T_k$ is linear and (4) says that $T_k$ applied to each such simplex is itself a linear combination of simplices lying in the respective element of $U$, so overall $T_k(c)$ is a linear combination of simplices each lying in some element of $U$.